# Am I interpreting my fixed effects regression correctly?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to determine the impact of student debt on entrepreneurship. I used a FE model with data from 2003-2014 on each US state. So my explanatory variable is student debt in state i in year t-1. My dependent variable is new startups in state i in year t. I include many demographic control variables and year dummies to limit endogeneity concerns.

I ran my regression and found a significant negative coefficient on lagged student debt. I an interpreting this coefficient in the following way: In a given state in year t-1, an increase in student debt of $1 will result in a B unit decrease in new startups.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: What is a B unit? Where does B come from?

Comment: As in the beta coefficient attached to student debt in the regression

Comment: Your explanation is correct given that the estimate beta coefficient is negative and identity link function is used.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm not really familiar with identity link functions, how would they be applied here?

Comment: You just say fixed effect model. For example, you can use log link function to fit a fixed effect model, which is used when response variable is positive skewed, like income.  identity link function means no transformation.

Comment: Oh I see! Yes it is an identity link function, then.